# C# .Net Core - Find and replace a single entry in IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to use IMemoryCache to speed up my application by not always accessing the database, where possible.

I have a few methods to get/set the cached object, which is a List, however, I have an update record, which logically should update the database, and update the cache, currently I have it to Remove the cached list and get the latest, which is not feasible.

Is there a way to update a single record in the Cached list of items and store it in cache again?

My current Update method is:

```
public virtual T Update(T entity) {
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Context.SaveChanges();
    
    MemoryCache.Remove(CacheName);
    GetAll();
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll() => CachedList.AsQueryable();
```

CachedList is a property I am using which handles get or create, and also handles simple set.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd be inclined to implement my own `IMemoryCache` using a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>` - then you can compose the update-logic with [AddOrUpdate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I did think about something similar to that, however, I wish to use what has been provided with .NET Core, if possible, trying not to re-invent the wheel.